# How to transplant Mozilla Thunderbird profile folder from Windows 8.1 to Xubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows, thunderbird

I have recovered my Mozilla Thunderbird profile folder from a now defunct Windows 8.1 installation. I tried to a copy it into a new installation on my newly setup machine running Xubuntu 18.04.3 - in vain.

I have been following the instructions as stated on the official Mozilla page:

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Thunderbird#Linux_and_Unix

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Sharing_a_profile_between_Windows_and_Linux

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Files_and_folders_in_the_profile_-_Thunderbird

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Moving_your_mail_storage_location_-_Thunderbird

Can someone please offer a step by step guide for someone who does not know anything about Linux? Thank you.

Comment: Do you have the entire profile? xxxxxxxx.default? I just start Thunderbird and it creates new profile and profile.ini. I then just copy entire profile to same .thunderbird folder and backup & edit profile.ini with my xxxxxxxx.default replacing new one it created.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make new profile and then replace those files with "old ones" from windows. I used to do that with Firefox by copying places.sqlite from windows to linux. This, at least, worked. The other way around (linux->windows) did not.

It may, and certainly will not work with everything but you may get some data from databases (.sqlite files).